# Animate UIImageView tint color dosent work

Tags: objective-c, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, tintcolor

I have UIImageView which i'm assigning UIImage after iv'e  applied

```
 imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate)
```

to the image.

I'm trying to animate the tint sing this code :

```
UIView.transitionWithView(imageV!, duration: 0.275, options: [.BeginFromCurrentState , .TransitionCrossDissolve], animations: { () -> Void in
        imageV?.tintColor = globalColor
        imageV?.setNeedsDisplay()
        }, completion: nil)
```

But it's simply jump to the final color. **Any Suggestions? Thanks!**

Comment: are u resolve this issue ?

Comment: @puko Not yet..

Answer (score 1):

For Objective-C it looks like:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f
                      delay:0.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                 animations:^
{
    imageView.tintColor = color;
}
                 completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't animate the tintColor property of the image view.

Theres only a handful UIView properties that you can animate.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html

I had a similar issue and how I solved it is that I created a second imageView with the second tintColor. Then when needed a change in color, I animate the transition between the two UIImageViews, giving the impression that the color was changing.

Comment: However the docs doesn’t say it explicitly, the tintColor property of the UIImageView is animatable. If needed then I will post a sample code, since I thought as you, but magically it simply works.